# How to put this bash pipe command into a variable, and then execute?

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-cros-linux-gnu)
command:

```
file=fileName; line=3;

head -$line $file | tail -1;
```

In my usage, the above line is constructed by a bash script.
How can I put the above command in a bash variable, and then execute it?

```
cmd='head -$line $file | tail -1;'
```

To run, `$cmd` in back quotes does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you wish to evaluate the string `"$cmd"`, you can tell bash to do so with `eval`.  eg. `eval "$cmd"`.  There are many pitfalls.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @viv3k, `eval $cmd` is _exceptionally_ buggy. If someone really wants to use `eval` and accept its pitfalls (which are serious, and on account of which one should use the approaches described in BashFAQ #50 instead), they should use `eval "$cmd"`, **with the quotes**. Without the quotes, you're string-splitting your variable's contents, expanding each word resulting from the splitting as a glob, _concatenating all the results of those operations together into a single string_, and running that _new_ string through the parser as code.

Comment: ...so if you have `cmd='ls *.txt'`, and you run `eval $cmd` in a directory that contains a file named `$(rm -rf ~).txt`, someone is going to have a _very_ bad day. (There are plenty of accidental failure cases as well as the malicious ones, but count that as a particularly egregious example)

Comment: `the above line is constructed by a bash script` Why are you "constructing line to be executed" with a bash script? What do you mean by that?